# Postfix Limit mail for domain from IP range

Tags: postfix, spam, spam-filter

I have multiple domains and email accounts on my postfix server. All of them get slammed with spam despite all my attempts to get it under control, I broke down and started paying for a pass external spam filtering service. Which helped tremendously.

One domain domain however is still getting slammed with spam. While investigating I noticed the spam is coming in directly to our server and not through the spam filtering service. So I am wanting to do is modify my Postfix configuration so that email for that domain name and only that domain name can be delivered from the Spam Filtering services IP addresses.

The reason why I am looking to do it on a by domain method is because a couple of the domains on the server did not have spam issues (more a matter of smart internet users). So I never signed them up for the spam server. This ruled out the ability to just set ip tables to allow smtp traffic only form the spam filtering service's IP Addresses.

Anyone got a way I can do this?

**Edit:**
To clarify all mail (minus 1 or 2 domains) on the server is delivered to a outside spam service first. Then spam service does their magic and delivers it to us. So for a domain using this service if the SMTP traffic is not from the IP address of the Spam Service. I just want the mail rejected or sent into a black hole. As the DNS changes were made weeks ago. So and direct connection to the server for a domain using that spam service is going to be spam.

Answer (score 2):

From your description,  I'm translating your question to: how to setup postfix so

> IF postfix receive an email with **recipient domain is example.net** AND **IP address ism't IP address of spam filtering** THEN send the email to spam filtering service.

The possible solution is using [Postfix Per-Client/User/etc. Access Control a.k.a. Postfix restriction classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html).

First you need to define the `check_recipient_access` in your restriction stack, for example in `smtpd_recipient_restriction`. Also define `smtpd_restriction_classes` in main.cf

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = spamfiltering
smtpd_recipient_restriction = 
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/spammydomain
    ...other restriction...
```

Then in `main.cf`, we define the spammy domain, for example: example.net

```
example.net    spamfiltering
```

Then in `main.cf` define custom filtering for all IP address except spam filtering IP Address (for example 192.168.1.168)

```
spamfiltering = check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/spamfilter, permit
```

For file `/etc/postfix/spamfilter`, put this line

```
192.168.1.168/32   PERMIT
0.0.0.0/0          REJECT
```

It will REJECT all email **intended to** example.net domain, except if it came from 192.168.1.168

Comment: I edited it, but also maybe I don't understand you part. Say our domain is "receiver1.net". I want to reject if the connection IP isn't X for mail coming to "receiver1.net" regardless of who sent the email, but only if it's to "receiver1.net" and not "receiver2.net". Forgive me if i'm taking in circle's Post fix confuses me some times. I can never remember if "sender" in it is my domain when receiving email or their domain when i'm receiving.

Comment: ah I misread your question. It almost bedtime in my timezone... See my updated answer

Comment: Shouldn't 'example.net spamfiltering' be in /etc/postfix/spammydomain and not main.cf?